# find out which form does the clicked item belongs from

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a series of forms in my html, the intention is that when the user clicks on the "continue" button, the current one disappears and the next one shows up. However I was wondering if there is a way of getting which "continue" button was pressed (that is, of which form) so to just have a piece of code that basically checks and hides the current form and shows up the next one without requiring id's or such.

I tried a couple of things but none worked so I won't be posting here the code (it honestly just "broke" the website anyways.

Comment: How are your forms structured? Do you have multiple forms in one page?

Comment: Are you using any sort of javascript library?

Comment: @quantumSoup: I have multiple forms in one page

@Ben: I'm doing this with raw javascript =), but I'm not agains using any frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a breeze if you use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

```
$(function() {
   // Attach click handler to your buttons
   $("button, input[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Hide the correct form
      var thisForm = $(this).parents("form").hide();
      // Show the form after this one
      thisForm.nextAll("form:first").show();
   });
});
```

That'll handle hiding and showing the forms for you too. It assumes your buttons are either `<button>` or `<input type="submit">`, and your form elements are within the same parent.

Of course, if you have buttons elsewhere on the page which don't have this behaviour, then you need to add a class such as `formContinue` to your buttons of interest, and change the third line in the code above to:

```
$("button.formContinue, input[type=submit].formContinue").click(function(e) {
```

Comment: quick question, if "form:first" gets me the next sibling, how can I get ahold of the previous one?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, siblings("form:first") will get you the first form in the series. To get the previous or next form use thisForm.prev() and thisForm.next(). If you have other elements between forms then use thisForm.prevAll("form:first") and thisForm.nextAll("form:first"). I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest might be to give each such "continue button" a different `id`, which makes it trivial to identify (e.g. you could have the `id` be the form's `id` concatenated with the string `'_cnt'` or the like).  But if you're using jquery, the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method lets you trivially-easily find an object's "parent", so in that case I'd recommend just making the continue buttons immediate children of their respective forms.  (If you're not using *some* good JS framework, like the popular jquery, to tide you across browser incompatibilities &c, consider doing so... they're *really* useful!-).

Answer (score 0):

For every input element you can obtain the parent form by `element.form`. From inside every element you can locate the next sibling by [`element.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nextSibling).

Here's the math:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 3436720</title>
        <script>
            function showNext(form) {
                var next = nextSibling(form, 'FORM');
                form.style.display = 'none';
                if (next) next.style.display = 'block';
            }
            function nextSibling(element, tagname) {
                var next = element.nextSibling;
                while (next && next.tagName != tagname) next = next.nextSibling;
                return next;
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            .hide { display: none; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>Form 1<button onclick="showNext(this.form)">next</button></form>
        <form class="hide">Form 2<button onclick="showNext(this.form)">next</button></form>
        <form class="hide">Form 3<button onclick="showNext(this.form)">next</button></form>
        <form class="hide">Form 4<input type="submit"></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You may be just starting with JavaScript. But I'd recommend to end up using a JavaScript library which insanely eases DOM manipulation, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com). Here's how it can look like with help of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 3436720 with jQuery</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('button.next').click(function() {
                    $(this).closest('form').hide().next('form').show();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .hide { display: none; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>Form 1<button class="next">next</button></form>
        <form class="hide">Form 2<button class="next">next</button></form>
        <form class="hide">Form 3<button class="next">next</button></form>
        <form class="hide">Form 4<input type="submit"></form>
    </body>
</html>
```